# about the function strcpy_s

Tags: c++, string, strcpy

I want to output the smallest letters of the first letter of three countries, this is the code:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<string>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    void smallest_string(char str[][30], int);
    int i;
    char country_name[3][30];
    for (i = 0; i < 3; i++)
        cin >> country_name[i];
    smallest_string(country_name, 3);
    system("pause");
}
void smallest_string(char str[][30], int n)
{
    int i;
    char string[30];
    ***strcpy_s(string, str[0]);***
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
        if (strcmp(str[i], string) < 0)
            strcpy_s(string, str[i]);
    cout << endl << "the smallest string is:" << string << endl;
}
```

In this code `strcpy_s(string, str[0]);`, it seems can be deleted. Why?

Comment: What do you think will be in `string` when you delete that line? (Also why are you using `char` arrays instead of `std::string`?)

Comment: it seems there is no need assigning to each of the elements of  string[30]

Comment: You're writing C++ so use `std::vector` and `std::string` rather than raw arrays of `char[]`

Comment: `strcpy_s` takes **three** arguments, not two.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The line `strcpy_s(string, str[0]);` is essential if you want your loop to start from `i = 1`.

However, since you start it from `i = 0` it is not strictly required if you also define the following start condition: `string[0] == CHAR_MAX` and `string[1] == 0`. But if that is not the case then you will experience undefined behavior.